# OSX/Cocoa : adding objects on the Dock

Tags: macos, cocoa, dock

For one of my software, I might need to have to add some objects that could have the same behavior as any of object already present (apps/stack etc.), having a contextual menu.

Is it some how possible ?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. That's the domain of applications, files and folders, configured by the user. You do, however, have the ability to add a menu to your own application whose icon appears in the Dock.

You might consider menu extras, but those come with their own set of problems. One in particular is the OS making them disappear when space in the menu bar becomes tight.

Comment: Then is it possible to add programaticaly folders for exemple ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler : There are some really hacky ways to do it, I understand, but I wouldn't do it, because as I said, the Dock is for the user, and for no one else.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler You shouldn't do that even if you can find a way. This isn't Windows where every application feels free to put whatever crap it wants all over the user's environment. If a user wants your application in their Dock they'll put it there.

Comment: Actually it was the only purpose of my app. Juste add as specified by the user the asked folders.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler : If that's the case, then do consider a menu extra.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler What's the point of an application for that when the user can just do it directly?

Comment: I wanted to add my hard drives on the dock when they're plugged in.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler If you only want specific drives to appear you can add them, and they'll simply remain on the Dock inaccessible when the drive isn't plugged in. If you want all drives to appear you can either try adding /Volumes to the dock or you can just turn on the option that makes drives appear on the Desktop (instead of the Dock).

Comment: Yeah I already did your second solution but I liked the way I work on Ubuntu with Unity (actually it's the only thing I like on the unity dock)